# the meaning of 'spin ' here

Tags: word-meaning

> It’s not impossible to imagine an outcome in which Keystone XL would
>   have survived to live its life to the fullest. However, the project
>   was barely conceived before **spin** doctors diagnosed at least two
>   major flaws that would prove to be fatal: timing and politics.
>
> [Obituary: Keystone XL, age 7, choked on political baloney](http://business.financialpost.com/news/energy/jen-gerson-keystone-xl-achieved-a-symbolic-power-that-elevated-its-public-profile-beyond-its-actual-importance)

What is the meaning of '**spin**' here? Is it a noun?

Comment: [***spin doctor***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/spin+doctor)

Comment: I would not vote to close, because this definition of *spin* is advanced and not intuitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a noun. In this context, "spin" means "propaganda loosely based on facts". The idea is you "spin" the truth, distorting it into a convincing lie. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(public_relations)) has a pretty good article on it.

I have never heard of the term "spin doctor" before, but it appears that it means:

> A person who publicizes favorable interpretations of the words and actions of a public figure, especially a politician.

source:
http://www.thefreedictionary.com/spin+doctor

Comment: Its a fairly commonly used term in US politics.